# Groovy - case sensitive attribute access after inheritance

Tags: class, inheritance, groovy

I stumbled over a strange behavior using Groovy-Class inheritance.

Giving following example:

```
class Foobar {
    def ACcessible = 1
    def AlsoAccessible = 2
}

class Foo {
    def ACcessible = 3
    def alsoAccessible = 4
    def NonAccessible = 5
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

def foobar = new Foobar()
def bar = new Bar()


println "foobar.ACcessible = " + foobar.ACcessible
println "foobar.AlsoAccessible = " + foobar.alsoAccessible
println "bar.ACcessible = " + bar.ACcessible
println "bar.alsoAccessibleProb = " + bar.alsoAccessible
println "bar.NonAccessible = " + bar.NonAccessible
```

It seems that the accessibility of attributes is dependent on the case of the variable names. Within the inherited class, only variable names starting with a lower-case letter or with two upper-case letters are accessible.

Therefore, the script produces following output:

```
foobar.ACcessible = 1
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: NonAccessible for class: Bar
foobar.AlsoAccessible = 2
Possible solutions: nonAccessible
bar.ACcessible = 3
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: NonAccessible for class: Bar
bar.alsoAccessibleProb = 4
```

Is there a language specification in Groovy I missed that explains this behavior?

Comment: IIRC Groovy has some "magic" where it determines if an identifier is a type name based on adhering to `JavaConvention`.  If so, that seems to have gone badly wrong here.  (I'll see if I can dig up a reference, because this could just be my faulty memory from 3 years ago.)

Comment: Aha, I'm not imagining it - http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td389860|a389866

Comment: TL;DR:  Don't use upper case first letters for variables and parameters